# Möbius transformation of the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Let $\phi_{\alpha}(z)=\frac{z-\alpha}{1-\bar{\alpha}z}$ for  $0<|\alpha|<1$

Find all the line $L$ in the complex plane such that $\phi_{\alpha} (L)=L$

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Möbius transformations take lines and circles to lines and circles.  The lines are distinguished from circles in that they go through $\infty$ (in the extended complex plane, i.e. the Riemann sphere).  What does this transformation do to $\infty$, and what does it map to $\infty$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{-\bar{\alpha}}$, $\frac{1}{\bar{\alpha}}$ respectively. Can you give me more hint please?

Comment: you mean that the line is $y=\frac{Im\alpha}{Re\alpha}x$

Comment: Almost... you could also have $\text{Re}(\alpha) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\CC}{\mathcal{C}}$
In this case $f$ is a 2-cycle (i.e. $f\circ f=Id$. ًWe take $f=-\Phi_\alpha$). Let $a$ be a fixed point of $f$ ($a^2=\frac \alpha{\bar \alpha}$). Let $\CC$ be the circle of center $\frac1{\bar \alpha}$  and passing through $a$, $L_1$ the straight line $(a,\alpha)$, $L_2$ the straight line orthogonal to $L_1$ and passing through $\frac1{\bar \alpha}$, and $b$ is symmetric to $a$ with respect to $L_1$.

Then the only invariant lines by $f$ are $L_1$, $L_2$, and the only circles invariant by $f$ are:

a) The circles which  passes through $a$ and $b$.

b) The circles  which are symmetric with respect to $L_1$ and orthogonal to $\CC$.

In general, we have the following Theorem (cf: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ajmsc.2012.03.005).

> Let $f$ be a $2-$cycle  such that $\infty$ is not a fixed point. Let
>   $\alpha\in{\Bbb C}$ such that $f(\alpha)=\infty$. Let $a$ be a fixed
>   point of $f$, $\CC$ the circle of center $\alpha$ and passing through
>   $a$, $L_1$ the straight line $(a,\alpha)$, $L_2$ the straight line
>   orthogonal to $L_1$ and passing through $\alpha$, and $b$ is symmetric
>   to $a$ with respect to $L_1$.
>
> Then the only invariant lines by $f$ are $L_1$, $L_2$, and the only
>   circles invariant by $f$ are:
>
> - The circles which  passes through $a$ and $b$.
> - The circles  which are symmetric with respect to $L_1$ and
>     orthogonal to $\CC$.